# Cypress tests taking too long when running in CI pipeline

Tags: azure, automation, continuous-integration, cypress

My cypress tests are running in about 7 minutes on my local machine pointing to a static site in Azure.

When they run the Azure CI pipeline on a build controller (on-prem) they take 14 minutes pointing to that exact same static site in Azure.

I also tried to run the tests from an Azure VM to that same static site and they take 14 minutes.

Why such a big gap ? I checked the CPU and the RAM on the build controller and the Azure VM and it's not bad so what other elements could contribute to the slowness?

See benchmark in attachment
[image]

Thanks

Comment: We are experiencing similar behavior. Running cypress tests locally usually takes between 7-10 minutes, but in Azure DevOps pipeline (Windows machine) this takes around 20+ minutes. Even Jest snapshot tests that run in 13 seconds flat on a local macbook, take approximately 1 min 45 s to run in pipeline. No idea why it's so slow.

Comment: For now the workaround I found was to use this really nice package : https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-parallel

it allows you to run your cypress tests in parallel and saves you a lot of time

Comment: @onimougwo but will it work with azure?